# Переопределение метода getView() класса SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android

Необходимо ли при переопределении метода `getView()` явно вызывать в нём методы `bindView()` и `newView()`?

не вызовутся ли они во второй раз уже после того как `getView()` вернёт результат?

Comment: Посмотрите исходник этого адаптера. Если вы при переопределении вызываете супер-метод, то самому не надо вызывать `newView()` и `bindView()`, супер-метод это сделает за вас. Если не вызываете супер-метод, то надо самому все делать.

Comment: а где именно можно на это посмотреть, просто Android studio под рукой сейчас нет @pavlofff

Comment: @MishaFauzel http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java#CursorAdapter.getView%28int%2Candroid.view.View%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup%29

Comment: для того чтобы сохранить пользовательский ввод при прокрутке, при повторном использовании View сохраняется старый ввод,что вносит нехилую такую путаницу. @pavloff

Comment: ведь по идее Android должен знать есть ли уже что то в этом View, самый быстрый способ, как мне показалось это переопределить getView(), и извините хотел спросить, программирование на Android ваша профессия? @pavlofff

Comment: Если проблема в том, что в айтемах появляется что то, что вводилось ранее в другом месте, то при биндинге в айтем нужно предварительно очищать виджеты от содержимого, делать `setText("")`

Comment: это мой же вопрос, просто проблема в том что при работе именно с этим кодом, высвечивается 3-4 последних ввода, а если до того как будет вызван метод bindView(), сохранить введённый текст в массив  типа String, а затем проверить уже после вызова есть ли в массиве что-то именно для этого набора данных @pavlofff

Comment: Переоформите вопрос так, чтобы в нем была ваша реальная проблема, которую вы не можете решить.